# Need assistance regarding UILocalNotification permissions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
```

This code is for registering for `UILocalNotification` and this will also popup this:

[image]

Question 1: At this state when user has not chosen any option, How do I get notified when user choose one of the option which is `Don't Allow` or `Ok`? So I can execute app accordingly.

--

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *current = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
UIUserNotificationType required = UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
if(current.types & required) {
    NSLog(@"Permission present: %lu", (unsigned long)current.types);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Permission not present: %lu", (unsigned long)current.types);
}
```

When app will launch after first time, with this code I am trying to fetch which permission user has allowed (maybe he goto settings and disabled all types of notification alerts).

Question 2: I am simply getting numbers in `log` like `7` for the types of permission I am checking and `0` if user has not allowed the `UILocalNotification`. How to check for permissions correctly?

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings. This will be called when the user does any approval or denial action.

Comment: For checking supported type you can check  if( (types &  UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge) . That is you can do bitwise AND with the type you needed with types property of UIUserNotificationSettings.

Answer (score 1):

I used the below method in one of my project to determine whether the user has given permission or not, or whether he/she actually turned off the notifications in settings. Put this method in Appdelegate and check

```
-(BOOL)notificationServicesEnabled {
BOOL isEnabled = NO;

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]){
    UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];

    if (!notificationSettings || (notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone)) {
        isEnabled = NO;
    } else {
        isEnabled = YES;
    }
} else {
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    if (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) {
        isEnabled = YES;
    } else{
        isEnabled = NO;
    }
}

  return isEnabled;
}
```

Then you can simple check with condition

```
if([self notificationServicesEnabled])
```